# Gradle sync fail in Android Studio 3.0.1 (latest version) even after downloading all Ndk/Sdk bundles

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am new to Android Studio. How can I resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: Screenshots are OK, but please also put your error in text format in the question. Remember that screenshots are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers, and as such are not the most helpful format to present textual information.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @manash-jyoti-baruah Has this been resolved? If yes, Could you please post how did you resolve this. Thanks in advance.